# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined, inside Object.keys, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using: `method = () => { }` so i don't need to bind the function

here's my class:

```
class Form extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      disabledFields: [],
    };

  }

  executeCode = ( methodCode ='', params = {} ) => {
    const result = crudCode[methodCode](params);
    if (result && result.newStates) {

      Object.keys(result.newStates).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) {
          this.setState( {  nada: 'nada' });
        });
    }
  }
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
> 48 |         this.setState( {  nada: 'nada' });
```

what I'm doing wrong, I've already used this type of function and setState, but i don't know this time it does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use an arrow function in your `map` callback:

```
Object.keys(result.newStates).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) {
    this.setState( {  nada: 'nada' });
});
```

So, it is not bound to `this`.

This will work instead:

```
Object.keys(result.newStates).map((keyName, keyIndex) => {
    this.setState( {  nada: 'nada' });
});
```

Comment: If you don't mind, could you use your gold badge to mark as duplicate?